# Scala create group of elements

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to create a group of elements in a message as in below image

[image]

**Updated:**

```
 case class Element(key:String;value:String)
```

Message can be represented something like below

```
 case class Msg(field1:Element,field2:Group)
```

`Group`->represents the repeating group - I need help to define group and sub 
 groups

The element defines the **key=value** combination which is repeated in groups

The following are some points

1. Are the "fields" attributes of a FixMessage?

   -Yes they are attributes of a Fix Message and each field is represented as 
   `case class Element(key:String;value:String)`
2. Repeating group 
    they are `Element` repeating no of times
3. Are the keys and values all Strings?

   -Consider them as string for now
4. Field N (Field 1, Field 2, etc) represent different types?

   -Yes they represent it as different data types.But for now we can take them as of same data type to make it simple.

Output :

**key2=value2** ;`key3=value3;key4=value=4;key3=value3;key4=value=4`;**key2=valu‌​
     e2;**`key3=value3;key‌​4=value4;key3=value‌​3;key4=value4`

Explaination

The group `key2=value2` is repeating 2 times 
The sub group is `key3=value3;key4=value=4;key3=value3;key4=value=4` which is gain repeating 2 times in each group (`key2=value2`) respectively

Comment: @GhostCat hope it is bit clear now

Comment: `trait Group{val ele = List[myType](); val grp = List[Group]()}`

Comment: @jwvh thanks.so in order to achieve my goal to list...what possible approach should i follow.I extend all my classes with the trait group and add element  to list

Comment: By the way, this question is actually worse than the previous one. It is not clear what ultimate goal is. It's not clear how the java sample code solves the stated problem (or even its relationship to the problem). And the type names are so generic (Type1, Type2) that they don't provide any hint as to what the actual intent is.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco hope it clarifies now

Comment: @code25 Not quite. You're presenting a hierarchy with some labels, but it's still not clear what they are supposed to represent. Are the "fields" attributes of a FixMessage? are they attributes of a particular RepeatingGroup? is a RepeatingGroup a single entity or a list of Groups? Are the keys and values all Strings? does Field N (Field 1, Field 2, etc) represent different types? or do they represent names of different attributes that all share the same type?

Comment: @code25 Have you examined the approach used by this library? https://github.com/mhotchen/fix-protocol (assuming that's the domain you're interested in)

Comment: @Alvaro Carrasco yes i have but it doesnt  encounter the group part.I am facing issue in grouping

Comment: I am not sure what is not clear in question can anyone explain me so that i can improve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152308/discussion-between-coder25-and-alvaro-carrasco).

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I have answered your queries .hope it clarifies the question now

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov can you please help me in this question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the domain correctly, something like this should work:

```
case class Message(entries: List[Entry])

case class Entry(name: String, value: Value)
trait Value
object Value {
  case class Single (v: String) extends Value
  case class Group (entries: List[List[Entry]]) extends Value
}

Message(
  Entry("Key 1", Value.Single("Value 1")),
  Entry("Key 2", Value.Group(
    List(
      List(
        Entry("Key 3", Value.Single("Value 3")),
        Entry("Key 4", Value.Single("Value 4"))
      ),
      List(
        Entry("Key 3", Value.Single("Value 5")),
        Entry("Key 4", Value.Single("Value 6"))
      )
    )
  ))
)
```

Of course some helper functions could be created to make a nicer DSL for it.

Comment: Yes u understood it clearly.but I need not pass List of list to achieve this .I may require method to add the group and sub groups to it.But not sure something like`trait Group{val ele = List[myType](); val grp = List[Group]()}`

Comment: I have answered your queries .Please have a look

Comment: `key2=value2` is a group which can be repeated n times ... followed by a subgroup.